# Body Language Pattern Calculations?

Tags: combinatorics

Help! I have a real-world problem that I don't know how to calculate an answer. I am teaching a communications class on body language, and I want to show the vast number of combinations possible in combining gestures and facial expressions and stance, etc. I usually have students do an exercise to create and copy movement patterns. Each pattern is 4 counts...and there are 4 possible body locations that are "touched" or "clapped". Think of the kid's song "Head and Shoulders, Knees and Toes...only in this version, we do Head, Shoulders, Clap and Slap (Slap the hands on thighs). Any location can be repeated in any order, so there are no exclusions. How do I calculate the number of POTENTIAL combinations made? Your help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: If I understand the question right, 4 choices for each of the 4 counts, makes for 4*4*4*4 = 256 choices in all

Answer (score 1):

Here's a just-the-facts answer, without much explanation of where the numbers come from.

Assuming that:

- 'slapping' and 'clapping' are not different operations (just that we
  say 'clapping' when referring to hands), and
- both  hands must touch the same body part at the same time, and
- the hands must touch different knees or different thighs, if either was the body part chosen for this count, and
- there is no distinction between, say, "left-hand-slaps-left-knee + right-hand-slaps-right-knee" and "left-hand-slaps-right-knee and right-hand-slaps-left-knee" (or equivalently, if the latter combination is forbidden)

then there are $4^4=256$ possibilities.

If we drop the fourth assumption, there are $6^4=1.296$ possibilities.

If we drop the third and fourth assumptions, there are $(1+1+4+4)^4=10.000$ possibilities.

If we drop the second assumption as well, some ambiguity is introduced, but probably it's most reasonable to say that you can't have one hand slap another hand which is slapping one of the other body parts. In this case, there are $(1+5\cdot4)^4=194.481$ possibilities.

[Culture note: The phenomenon that one often obtains truly massive amounts of possibilities from making a rather small number of choices among a rather limited amount of moves, is sometimes called *combinatorial explosion*, and is fundamentally a consequence of exponential growth.]

Comment: Your assumptions are basically correct. For each of the 'locations', both hands work / touch the same location (head, shoulders, clap=the hands touch each other, thighs- both hands slap on the coordinating thigh)....But you can be repeat the location any number of times in a pattern...so you can have head, head, head, head....or head, slap, slap, head...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if
this is an answer 
to your question,
but this was just published
in the
ACM Transactions on Graphics (TOG),
Volume 36 Issue 1, October 2016.

https://dl.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=2983620

The title is
"PERFORM: Perceptual Approach for Adding OCEAN Personality to Human Motion Using Laban Movement Analysis".

Here is the abstract:

A major goal of research on virtual humans is the animation of expressive characters that display distinct psychological attributes. Body motion is an effective way of portraying different personalities and differentiating characters. The purpose and contribution of this work is to describe a formal, broadly applicable, procedural, and empirically grounded association between personality and body motion and apply this association to modify a given virtual human body animation that can be represented by these formal concepts. Because the body movement of virtual characters may involve different choices of parameter sets depending on the context, situation, or application, formulating a link from personality to body motion requires an intermediate step to assist generalization. For this intermediate step, we refer to Laban Movement Analysis, which is a movement analysis technique for systematically describing and evaluating human motion. We have developed an expressive human motion generation system with the help of movement experts and conducted a user study to explore how the psychologically validated OCEAN personality factors were perceived in motions with various Laban parameters. We have then applied our findings to procedurally animate expressive characters with personality, and validated the generalizability of our approach across different models and animations via another perception study.

Comment: Thanks, Marty. I've actually worked with Laban for a dance-application...It's marvelous (but extremely complicated) for the students that I'm currently working with....however, the concepts do help them to 'see' movements in 3D....I hadn't heard of the recent article, so I'll look it up...many thanks!